# Recognition of prebuilt datetimeV2 entity in LUIS

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, direct-line-botframework

We are using **DateTimeV2** French module. The recognition is not working as expected.
We are facing trouble in the following scenario:
For `query = 13/02/2018`, the value recognized is `13th Feb 2018` but if the date specified in less than 12, eg, `09/02/2018`, the value recognized is 2nd September 2018. There is a contradiction in these results and we are unable to process them further due to the same.

Please let me know if I am missing something out here or if there is go around for this.

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing something, there is a bug in the French recognizer, we already experienced the same thing.

### Origin of the problem:

In fact the problem seems to be around the order of the detection templates used by the recognizer: in French, dates are written in "day-month-year" format rather than in "month-day-year".
But if you have a look to the `DateTimeDefinitions` for French language [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/master/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Definitions/French/DateTimeDefinitions.cs#L70):

```
public static readonly string DateExtractor4 = $@"\b{MonthNumRegex}\s*[/\\\-]\s*{DayRegex}\s*[/\\\-]\s*{DateYearRegex}";
public static readonly string DateExtractor5 = $@"\b{DayRegex}\s*[/\\\-]\s*{MonthNumRegex}\s*[/\\\-]\s*{DateYearRegex}";
```

and the way they are used [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/master/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DateTime/French/Extractors/FrenchDateExtractorConfiguration.cs#L131), the problem will be that your date will fit DateExtractor4 first and the result will be used, whereas it was a value in format DateExtractor5.